# ⚠️ Unexpected Delegate Call for successful "Gnosis Safe: MultiSend 1.3.0"

Tags: gnosis-safe

The last few days, multisend transactions haven't shown up properly in Gnosis Safe Service. They show the red "⚠️ Unexpected Delegate Call" warning.

Example safe with one transaction: https://gnosis-safe.io/app/matic:0x30De31ACbB93b66c25b5793703F7F24Fb4d112EF/transactions/history

Looking at the transaction hash, it successfully executed the multisend: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x8147522a2b01e58194429744cc9791e7b669934524d1c450b43f2214b7ad9931
And the tokens were successfully transferred, e.g. to this account: https://polygonscan.com/address/0x761996f7258a19b6accf6f22e9ca8cdaa92d75a6#internaltx

This is the data returned from `@gnosis.pm/safe-service-client` when fetching the safe tx by safeTxHash:

```json
{
      "safe": "0x30De31ACbB93b66c25b5793703F7F24Fb4d112EF",
      "to": "0xA238CBeb142c10Ef7Ad8442C6D1f9E89e07e7761",
      "value": "0",
      "data": "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",
      "operation": 1,
      "gasToken": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "safeTxGas": 0,
      "baseGas": 0,
      "gasPrice": "0",
      "refundReceiver": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "nonce": 0,
      "executionDate": "2022-02-03T14:43:54Z",
      "submissionDate": "2022-02-03T14:35:02.440245Z",
      "modified": "2022-02-03T14:43:54Z",
      "blockNumber": 24504266,
      "transactionHash": "0x8147522a2b01e58194429744cc9791e7b669934524d1c450b43f2214b7ad9931",
      "safeTxHash": "0x1e2284e05fb9d074b45c4e2d5b9989d7f5aa804a0472e9fcc86c87978b604d53",
      "executor": "0x633C265C6C0e23CcA233e32f3F123Fc7470d2A13",
      "isExecuted": true,
      "isSuccessful": true,
      "ethGasPrice": "2503792436",
      "gasUsed": 103097,
      "fee": "258133488774292",
      "origin": null,
      "dataDecoded": null,
      "confirmationsRequired": 2,
      "confirmations": [
        {
          "owner": "0x761996F7258A19B6aCcF6f22e9Ca8CdAA92D75A6",
          "submissionDate": "2022-02-03T14:35:02.452343Z",
          "transactionHash": null,
          "signature": "0x0c65a285e473914744646de851e1dcb817ee4640119b4564e61e7df5a5a728967623cec18c14f3f785244ffc57450213630d34089880712558bb9794c3c133b51f",
          "signatureType": "ETH_SIGN"
        },
        {
          "owner": "0x633C265C6C0e23CcA233e32f3F123Fc7470d2A13",
          "submissionDate": "2022-02-03T14:43:54Z",
          "transactionHash": null,
          "signature": "0x000000000000000000000000633c265c6c0e23cca233e32f3f123fc7470d2a13000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
          "signatureType": "APPROVED_HASH"
        }
      ],
      "signatures": "0x000000000000000000000000633c265c6c0e23cca233e32f3f123fc7470d2a130000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010c65a285e473914744646de851e1dcb817ee4640119b4564e61e7df5a5a728967623cec18c14f3f785244ffc57450213630d34089880712558bb9794c3c133b51f",
      "transfers": [],
      "txType": "MULTISIG_TRANSACTION"
    }
```

Transfers is an empty array which I assume is the problem. Before, this showed up properly. How do I make the tx show up properly within Gnosis Safe Service again?

**When did this start happening?**
I'm not 100% sure but here is one clue:
On Jan 25 a test safe sent a multisend tx with actions (which I assume are the transfers) broken down.
On Jan 27, a similar tx doesn't show the sub transfers.

[image]

Here is that safe: https://gnosis-safe.io/app/rin:0xB815C4f62feA90e81032fe4AF7F094534DDb4784/transactions/history

The "Unexpected Delegate Call" didn't use to show in that safe before.

Answer (score 1):

We were working on improving how to flag dangerous MultiSend transactions. Everything should be back to normal now.

Comment: just got this as well, not clear/obvious why.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. We warn based on a curated list. We will [look into ways of clarifying this](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react/issues/3471).